on adf mapping data flow while writing data from adls to synapse dedicated pool i am facing issue while writing error to adls
on adf mapping data flow while writing data from adls to synapse dedicated pool i am facing issue while writing error to adls Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': Exception is happened while writing error rows to storage.
enter image description here
enter image description here
tryed with single aand batch both option


I got same error when I tried your scenario in the dataflow.
But when I disabled the staging in the dataflow sink and re-executed the pipeline, then the error got resolved and it gave me the expected results.

I have created name column with data type of varchar(4). So, any rows which have length of more than 4 for the name column from the source will be the error rows. You can see the rows less than 4 length were copied to the target table.

Error rows:

I have tried multiple times and whenever the staging is enabled the same error occurred. But this was not mentioned in the Documentation. Staging is very important in terms of performance when synapse tables were used as source or sink in the Dataflow. So, it seems to be a bug in the Dataflow rather than a document correction.
You can try the below possible workarounds in this case:

If your data is small, you can go ahead with above approach by disabling the staging.
If you have an Azure SQL database, then you can use that as dataflow sink as it does not require the staging in the dataflow and copy the errors to the ADLS. After dataflow activity, copy data from Azure SQL table to your target synapse table using copy activity.
If your error conditions are known, then make a custom error logic in the dataflow to copy the error rows into ADLS. Check this documentation which has an example about it.

